# nested dropdown menu using css

Tags: html, css

Trying out nested drop down menu using simple css.I am Trying to make navigation menu. All seems to work fine except that when I hover over the ABOUT US section under the NEW HERE, it shows me correct result. but the problem is it doesn't go away when i hover to the next section below it. how can i possibly fix that ? here's [The Link For the](https://codepen.io/Wil1478so596/pen/bXGBmx)  snippet for you to consider, kindly tell me where i am doing it wrong.
here's the code for you to see..

```
   .dropbtn2
  {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
  }
  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 169px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }

  /* Links inside the dropdown */
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    font-size:20px;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }

  /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
  .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

  /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    transition:none;
  }
  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    padding-top:15px;
    transition:ease-in-out .5s;
  }
  .dropdown:hover .dropbtn
  {
    background-color: #8300ff;
    color: #182318;
    padding-top: 500px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    transition: ease-out 0.5s;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow:none;

  }
  /* End*/
  .dropdown-content2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width:170px;
    left:170px;
    top:0;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  /* Links inside the dropdown */
  .dropdown-content2 a {
    color: black;
    font-size:20px;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }

  /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
  .dropdown-content2 a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

  /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
  .dropdown-content:hover .dropdown-content2 {
    display: block;
    transition:none;
  }
  .dropdown-content2 a:hover {
    padding-top:15px;
    transition:ease-in-out .5s;
  }
  .dropdown a:hover .dropbtn2
  {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    transition: ease-out 0.5s;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow:none;

  }

  /*TEST*/
```

Comment: There is so much wrong with your markup. You have multiple anchors and open divs inside an open li tag. Please create a reproducible example.

Comment: Please provide more HTML of your code

Comment: I have provided the codepen link, kindly go through it.. @RamChander

Comment: @Claire please check the codepen snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the element to hover in order to display your `dropdown-content` only when hovering your first link.

The value to replace is at line 182 of your codepen. Replace `dropdown-content:hover .dropdown-content2` by `.dropdown2:hover .dropdown-content2`.

*Lines 181-185:*

```css
  /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
  .dropdown2:hover .dropdown-content2 { /* change the hover element here */
    display: block;
    transition:none;
  }
```